# onClick в ListView и получение данных из таблиц по сравнению

Tags: java, android

Есть две таблицы в одной базе `tab1` и `tab2`. C `tab1` данные выводятся в `listView`, 
так скажем заголовки, как сделать, чтобы по клику на заголовку в `listView`, из tab2 выводились данные по сравнению колонки `num`?

*Пример: id=2 выводить из колонки num все стоки имеющие значение 2, id=3 выводить из колонки num все стоки имеющие значение 3*

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       //как реализовать?
    }
});
```

---

Таблица примерно имеет такой вид

```
tab1                        
-------------
id|name |some|  
-------------
1 |one  |text|
2 |two  |text|
3 |three|text|
4 |four |text|

tab2
-------------------------
id|name |value  |num    |   
-------------------------
1 |one  |some   |2      |
2 |two  |text   |2      |
3 |three|some   |3      |
4 |four |think  |3      |
5 |five |some   |3      |
6 |six  |think  |1      |
```

Comment: выводите по ID, если ID и name в обоих таблицах совпадают.

Comment: но в колонке num несколько одинаковых значений и выводить надо их всех

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Опишите саму задачу. У вас может быть проблема, связанная с тем, что ID присваивается не обязательно по порядку. В процессе внесения новых данных и их удаления ID будет присвоен следующим по счету, а не по позиции в таблице. А для решения вашей задачи ознакомтесь с разделом СУБД -выборка по  связи "один ко многим"